# Formatting ISODate from Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, isodate

In Mongodb I am storing date and time in ISODate format.

Which looks like this

```
ISODate("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00")
```

Using nodejs/javascript, how can I display the time component so I would get something like this

```
Time : 01:00
```

I am using momentjs to make this easier but from what I can tell momentjs does seem to support the ISODate format.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

JavaScript's Date object supports the ISO date format, so as long as you have access to the date string, you can do something like this:

```
> foo = new Date("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00")
Sat, 14 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT
> foo.toTimeString()
'17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)'
```

If you want the time string without the seconds and the time zone then you can call the getHours() and getMinutes() methods on the Date object and format the time yourself.

Comment: I used momentjs to do the formatting but had to pass getFullYear, getMonth, getDate, getHours and getMinutes by first extracting it from date object as you said.

Comment: Don't parse strings with the Date constructor, it is very inconsistent across implementations. While ISO formats are specified in ES5, not all browsers in use support it, and there are inconsistencies in how they are treated. E.g. "2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00" should be parsed as a local string (i.e. using system time zone settings), but ""2012-07-14" should be parsed as UTC.

Answer (score 34):

MongoDB's [ISODate()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates) is just a helper function that  wraps a JavaScript date object and makes it easier to work with ISO date strings.

You can still use all of the [same methods as working with a normal JS Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), such as:

```
ISODate("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00").toLocaleTimeString()

// Note that getHours() and getMinutes() do not include leading 0s for single digit #s
ISODate("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00").getHours()
ISODate("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00").getMinutes()
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use mongo  query like this

```
yearMonthDayhms: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", date: {$subtract:["$cdt",14400000]}}}

HourMinute: { $dateToString: { format: "%H-%M-%S", date: {$subtract:["$cdt",14400000]}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
// from MongoDate object to Javascript Date object

var MongoDate = {sec: 1493016016, usec: 650000};
var dt = new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00");
    dt.setSeconds(MongoDate.sec);
```