# The date format in mongodb could be yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss?

Tags: mongodb, date, format

I develop a application with node.js and mongodb.

I think the question is also available in javascript.
How can I convert the date format to the way I want,

like `yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss`?

Comment: That syntax for a date makes no sense, however the best way is within your JavaScript using its date functions

Comment: Did you ever google for "javascript parse date string"?

Answer (score 0):

```
> var a = new Date()
> a
ISODate("2013-01-01T13:50:36.839Z")
> a.getFullYear() + "/" + (a.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + a.getDate() + "/" + a.getHours() + "/" + a.getMinutes() + "/" + a.getSeconds()
2013/1/1/16/50/36
```

The code can be improved with string formatting methods. Also, take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486779/formatting-isodate-from-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M", date: {$subtract:["$cdt",14400000]}}}

This is how you can get all different formats  [image: dateformat]