# how to set timezone for mongodb datetime operations

Tags: mongodb, datetime

In mongodb, I know there are query operations which could be used on datetime object like :  [$hour](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/hour/),  [$dayOfWeek](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/dayOfWeek/)  etc.

But I've not found any manual about timezone settings, similar with what could be done in mysql like:

```
SET time_zone = '-8:00';
```

So, is there anyway to do similar things in mongodb?

Comment: Please don't post duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496489/how-to-do-query-with-timezone-settings-in-mongodb finish one version of the question at a time

Answer (score -1):

use this attribute

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```