# Convert & display UTC format of mongodb to EST format in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, timezone

**When i insert date time in mongodb, It's in UTC format**

> ISODate("2016-03-29T07:53:02.847Z")

**When i fetch this result, it's in IST**

> Tue Mar 29 2016 13:23:02 GMT+0530 (IST)

**I want to convert it to EST and display (only date and time)**

> Tue Mar 29 2016 02:56:22 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>
> Tue Mar 29 2016 02:56:22 ( **final output** )

*I have tried **node-time**, **moment js** etc. Did a lot of research but no result.* Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't. It's good practice to store in UTC. That way **every** timezone has a consistent view of the data. Timezones are a "client" issue, and not one for the database.

Comment: Related: ["How to do query with timezone settings in Mongodb"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496489/how-to-do-query-with-timezone-settings-in-mongodb) and ["Aggregating in local timezone in mongodb"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353740/aggregating-in-local-timezone-in-mongodb/)

Comment: You could store GMT offset in another field, to retain this information. Sqlserver has a data type for this exact purpose. Unfortunately mongo, and most other databases don't.

Comment: It doesn't save in local, it saves in UTC. You are probably confusing the output of something like `console.log(document)` which will "stringify" the date as a local value. Thats the `.toString()` method of a JavaScript `Date` object at work. You can do this in the shell as well `new Date().toString()` as opposed to `new Date()`, where one shows the "local string" and the other shows you that it's really a UTC date.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote it wrong. It saves in UTC but while fetching it converts UTC into IST. How ? Why ? Also You did not answer my second question in previous comment. @BlakesSeven

Comment: I just told you. `.toString()`! Go and try it. It's still a UTC value, but just "stringified" that way.

Comment: If i console.log(result of my query) it will give me [{ _id: 60,
    updated_at: Tue Mar 29 2016 15:43:25 GMT+0530 (IST),
    created_at: Tue Mar 29 2016 15:43:25 GMT+0530 (IST)
    }] whereas in mongo shell it is {
 "_id" : 60,
 "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-03-29T10:13:25.718Z"),
 "created_at" : ISODate("2016-03-29T10:13:25.718Z")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js works in node.js and has timezone support that can convert from UTC to any desired timezone: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

```js
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

You'll need to npm install moment timezone first

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

Comment: Can you please write a sample piece of code for me ??

Comment: Thanks i got it :) But is there any way i can do the same thing using mongodb aggregation instead of like this ?? Which one will be more efficient - fetching all records and then converting OR while querying only converting it ??

Comment: you could convert the start and end dates for the range from EST to UTC then run the query using the resultant dates

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help a lot :)