# Retrieve local time info with mongo $hour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am currently storing documents in mongodb with the help of a mongoose model. Querying by date works fine, but when I try to apply the $hour operator, it seems the ISO time is returned, and not the local time.

The current naming convention gives me a filename which includes the timestamp of the creation of the file: YYYYMMDDHHMMSS-foo-bar.file

Example: the import in the DB results in the following values for the timestamp parsed: 
`2014 04 02 07 57 33-foo-bar.file` gets parsed into `ISODate("2014-04-02T05:57:33Z")`.

When I do a query to find this item: I create new date objects like this (the dates are bogus and only for the sake of the querying approach I chose):

```
var begin = new Date(2014, 01, 10, 13, 00, 00);
var end = new Date(2014, 01, 10, 20, 00, 00);

db.pinas.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        [attributes I need...]
    }
, {
    $match: {
        'start_time': {
            $gte: begin, //ISODate
            $lt: end //ISODate
        }
    }
}]);
```

And again, these ISODates do not seem to store the timezone information although [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486779/formatting-isodate-from-mongodb) ISODates contain something: note the trailing +01:00 `ISODate("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00")`

Now I have two questions/problems:

I read somewhere that the point of returning datetime info in ISODates was to shift the "fine work" to the application rather than the DBMS, and that's true: it works in the case of parsing back the ISODatestring, I retrieve the correct time (I assume through knowing my local settings? What if the server was in another timezone?)

When I want to use the [$hour](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) date aggregation operator, how am I supposed to bring it back to local time? 
How does it work when I only return $hour?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.6 you can add a timezone attribute to get the hour in the correct time:

```
{ date: <dateExpression>, timezone: <tzExpression> }
```

for example:

```
{ $hour: {
    date: new Date("August 14, 2011Z"),
    timezone: "America/Chicago"
} }
```

for more details here is $hour documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no support for times in anything but UTC.  Anything you need to do in other time zones needs to be done client-side, so you would need to adjust the `$hour` values provided by MongoDB to local time in your own code.

See the [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) method of Date, and be mindful of daylight savings.

Not ideal, but that's how it is.

Comment: well that's what I was afraid of. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, MongoDB uses the standard UNIX epoch to store its time value. Epoch is always in UTC and offset for display should be handled client side.