# How to determine if a Express / Mongoose date is > 24 hours?

Tags: express, mongoose, mean-stack

My goal is to prevent an email from being sent more than once in a 24 hour period.  I have a schema:

```
var requestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    lastSent: Date
});
```

In my Express route I'm testing to see if the `lastSent` variable is more than one day ago...

```
var lastSent = new Date(existingRequest.lastSent);
var nextDate = new Date() - 1;

if (lastSent > nextDate) {
    if (constants.dev){ console.log('Signup request too soon'); }
} else {
    // Process request
}
```

... however I cannot seem to catch the date.  Logging the dates to the Express console shows this:

```
Last Sent: Tue Dec 16 2014 10:12:54 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Threshold: 1418746385786
```

Is there a chance that the date formats are mismatched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [The conversion of the ISODate coming from MongoDB is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488088/1577453)
2. You need to subtract in milliseconds, so you need to subtract `24*60*60*1000` to subtract a whole day.
3. The subtraction will return a timestamp, so you won't be able to use the usual [Date functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on that - you will need to construct a new date from the timestamp.

Try:

```
var nextDate = new Date(new Date() - 24*60*60*1000);
if(existingRequest.lastSent > nextDate) {...}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  The double-convert was the trick.  I had originally started subtracting milliseconds, so that was a snap to replace.  The conversion was the part that was causing my brain to hurt.  =)