# Convert time format to iso format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to convert this date format : Fri Jul 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Maroc (heure d’été)) (I don't what do we call it by the way ) to iso format (yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000 ) using javascript
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting ISODate from Mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486779/formatting-isodate-from-mongodb). The Mogodb part of the linked question is irrelevant. The solution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample snippet for your query. I hope it helps for your query.

```
    function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date("Fri Jul 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100"),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment(new Date("Fri Jul 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100")).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```