# wrap values with free text mysql json_object

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have this script that works well:

```
SELECT json_object(
  ...
  'lastEdited', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
)
```

and it prints out:

```
"lastEdited": "2018-12-27T18:02:48Z",
```

but I would like it to be:

```
"lastEdited": ISODate("2018-12-27T18:02:48Z"),
```

is it possible to wrap it with `ISODate()`?

Comment: @DanielE.yes, im writing script that reads from mysql and gives me jsons that i can insert to mongo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486779/formatting-isodate-from-mongodb