# MongoDB ISODate returns incorrect day and month

Tags: mongodb, date, mongo-shell, isodate

I'm trying to get the date a record/document was inserted into a MongoDB collection. I'm using the [ObjectId.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#objectid-gettimestamp) function to get the timestamp from the date.

The function returns an `ISODate` object, and going through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486779/formatting-isodate-from-mongodb?noredirect=1&lq=1), it looks like `ISODate` is just a wrapper around the native JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). But when I use the `getDay()` and `getMonth()` methods on the `ISODate` object, it returns incorrect results, though hours, minutes and year seems fine.

Usage (Mongo shell) -

```
> db.user.count()
1
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp()
ISODate("2018-10-26T12:52:31Z")
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getDay()
5
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getMonth()
9
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getFullYear()
2018
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getHours()
12
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getMinutes()
52
>
```

According to this -

```
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getDay()
5
> db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getMonth()
9
```

day is `5` and month is `9`, but it should be `26` and `10` respectively.

Screenshot -

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns day of the week (0-6, being 0 - sunday, 1 - monday, etc...), but [Date.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) returns day of the month.

```
db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getDate()
26
```

For **Date.getMonth()**, JavaScript `Date` return values 0 - 11, being 0 - january, 1 - february, etc.. 9 - october.

```
db.user.findOne()._id.getTimestamp().getMonth() + 1
10
```

LINK https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter