# How to convert isoDate to regular date 01/01/2022 in react, info is retrieved from mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am retrieving the data from mongodb, date comes in isoDate format, I want to convert it and render it. I'm using react.

This is my context.consumer:

```
<UserContext.Consumer>
 {
    ({ users }) => {
        return <div>
            <div>
                {users.map((u) => {
                    console.log(users)
                    return (
                        <div className='users_list'>
                            <h1>User Profile: {u.username}</h1>
                            <p>First Name: {u.firstName}</p>
                            <p>Last Name: {u.lastName}</p>
                            <p>Profile created: {u.createdAt}</p>
                            <h4>Tweets</h4>
                            </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

I appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159403/3537462

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use using ISODate().

```
ISODate("2022-09-14T01:00:00+01:00").toLocaleTimeString()

ISODate("2022-09-14T01:00:00+01:00").gethours()
ISODate("2022-09-14T01:00:00+01:00").getMinutes()
```

you can refer to this [MongoDB date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486779/formatting-isodate-from-mongodb)

In terms of rendering the date in react, I would recommend converting it in the backend then displaying it in react. Try using [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: encase you want to do it at the front end something like this would help.                           const date = new Date("2022-03-10T02:00:00Z");
const isoDate = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

Comment: thank you for replying! I tried modifying the front end only but it did not work.